# Log command list .append() doesn't work in discord.py

Tags: python, list, discord.py, append

I am making a Discord Bot using discord.py. 
For some reason `.append()` doesn't work on the log variable.

It gives me this error :

```
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I tested it on a normal script without discord.py, and it worked. 
But for some reason if I put the script on the bot it says that

Command Code :

````
global log
log = ["Spam Log :"]

@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, speed=None, *text):
  global log
  log.append(f"{text} - Spammed By {ctx.author} at {speed} speed.")
  if speed == None:
    await ctx.send("Please put a speed and text")
    return
  try:
    if str(ctx.guild.id) == "854947008304119809" and str(ctx.channel.id) == "868123051030638652":
      import asyncio
      global spamming
      spamming = True
      while spamming == True:
        await ctx.send(" ".join(text[:]))
        await asyncio.sleep(int(speed))
    else:
      await ctx.send("Please do it on <#868123051030638652>.")
        
  except:
    text = "An error accured, please try again with valid numbers."
    await ctx.send(text)
    ```
````

Comment: You probably have a command (async function) named `log`, check for `async def log(...)` in your code.

Comment: oh yeah i have that